# Vim movement delay on lines with 40 or more symbols

Tags: vim, macvim, delay

I like to visually delimit source code by long comment lines: In C++ I use 80 `/` characters, in Python I use 80 `#` characters, etc. Over the years I've noticed that Vim occasionally hiccups (stops responding for about half a second or so) when I move around; today I found that this only occurs on my delimiter lines.

For example:

```cpp
line 1
line 2
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
line 4
line 5
```

When the cursor is anywhere on line 3, any movement (up, down, page up, page down, left, right, `$`, `0`, ...) almost always exhibits the delay; on other lines it doesn't.

Playing around with this, I've found:

- The delay seems to occur on lines with a total of 40 or more symbols (`/`, `-`, `=`, `.`, `#` etc) anywhere on the line, not including `_` (perhaps because underscore is included in the Vim definition of a `word`).
- The delay does not seem to increase for longer lines. For example, lines of 1000 `/` characters have a similar delay to 40 `/` characters.
- The delay only occurs when starting a "new" movement from that line. Using OS key repeat to move through the line adds no delay.
- The delay does not seem related to syntax highlighting or plugins: I see the same behavior with `vim -u NONE`, `syntax off`, and `filetype=`.
- GUI Vim (gvim) does not seem to have this issue.

I'm using MacVim 8.0 from macports in the Terminal app on a MacBook Pro, but the default Apple-provided Vim 7.4 has the same behavior.

I haven't been able to find any mention of this on Google, Stack Overflow, or Super User, but it's very reproducible on my system.

Is this a known issue? Is there a runtime setting or build option that controls this (max supported symbols on a line or something), or a workaround that alleviates it?

Comment: Did you try debugging https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12213597/how-to-see-which-plugins-are-making-vim-slow#12216578  may reveal something even though not plugin related

Comment: @Michael Thanks for the tip - unfortunately the version of vim I use at work isn't built with `profile` support; at home I upgraded to the latest MacVim from macports to test this but that actually fixed the delay issue. I'm still interested in troubleshooting this since I can't change the version offered at work.